# node.js file write position parameter isn't working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a hard time getting node.js to write to my file at the correct position. Here's a demonstrative case of my problem:

```
fs = require('fs');
foo = fs.openSync('foo.txt','r+');
fs.writeSync(foo, "hello", 0, 5, 5);
fs.close(foo);
```

`foo.txt` has one line:

```
12345678901234567890
```

The expected output is for `foo.txt` to contain `12345hello1234567890`, but instead I'm getting `hello678901234567890`. I'm running `node v0.8.16`.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: I've been referencing these docs: [fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, offset, length, position)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the link to the docs say, the 2nd argument is a `Buffer`, but in your code you are passing a string. Doing this is causing Node to fall back to a different function signature that exists for backwards-compatability.

```
function(fd, str, position, encoding);
```

So pass the proper arguments

```
var buf = new Buffer("hello");
fs.writeSync(foo, buf, 0, buf.length, 5);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here it is what Node.js source code says:

lib\fs.js

```
 fs.writeSync = function(fd, buffer, offset, length, position) {
  if (!Buffer.isBuffer(buffer)) {
    // legacy string interface (fd, data, position, encoding)
    position = arguments[2];

    buffer = new Buffer('' + arguments[1], arguments[3]);
    offset = 0;
    length = buffer.length;
  }
  if (!length) return 0;

  return binding.write(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
};
```

If you look carefully if the second argument is not a buffer the **position** become **offset** and the offset become 0